# MyToolkit reduce memory usage

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, mytoolkit

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app and I'm using [MyToolkit](http://mytoolkit.io).Controls.HtmlView to display html content. Here is my code:

```
<mytoolkit:HtmlView Name="hvHtml" Html="Setting html content here..." FontSize="20" Loaded="hvHtml_Loaded"/>
```

On hvHtml_Loaded event I'm setting my simple html string:

```
hvHtml.Html = html;
```

Html string looks like this (sorry for Ukrainian language, but this doesn't matter):

```html
<p><em><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Увага!</strong></span> Читати огляд рекомендується під музичний супровід з цього плейлиста:</em></p>
<p><iframe></iframe></p>
<p>Зараз, після закінчення проходження <a href="/game/soma/">SOMA</a>, нового творіння ігрових жахів Frictional Games, я перечитую ці наївні ліричні рядки поета і стає моторошно від розуміння, наскільки влучно ці слова переказують зміст цієї гри. Немов розробники надихалися віршем (окрім багатьох процитованих фільмів, ігор і книжок). Тож поговорімо про SOMA і розберімося, чому так сталося, що найочікуваніший горор 2015 року виявився не зовсім горором, або зовсім не горором.</p>
<h3>Про сюжет</h3>
<p>Канадський молодик Саймон Джарретт за загадкових обставин потрапляє на підводний дослідницький комплекс PATHOS-2 через 100 років після свого пробудження вдома в Канаді. Сказати, що він розгублений — нічого не сказати. Довкола руїна, темрява, сліди крові і якась незрозуміла хрінь вилазить зі стін, стелі, і підлоги та простягається своїми механічно-органічними мацаками на всі боки. До того ж спорожнілими коридорами станцій комплексу бродять незрозумілі чудовиська і божевільні роботи. Геть незрозумілі і загадкові початкові лаштунки.</p>
<div><img class="wp-image-23304 size-full" src="http://playua.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/b4d73a241cec9cff9a5ac448efe31d69.jpg" alt="2015-09-20_00003"   /><p class="wp-caption-text">Мить розуміння, в яку халепу ти втрапив, завжди спантеличує</p></div>
<p>Інтрига манить на пошук відповідей. Хочеться з&#8217;ясувати і що сталося зі Саймоном, і куди ділося ціле століття, і що це за станція, і багато іншого. Однак заявлена на початку гри інтрига розвіюється протягом перших годин проходження після знайомства зі ще одним важливим персонажем Кетрін Чан, яка дає відповіді на більшість запитань.</p>
<p>Сюжет SOMA побудований за формулою: узяли трішки SystemShock 2, додали Bioshock, приправили Fallout, забрали увесь екшн і отримали SOMA. І це знову історія про те, як героя/обраного без пам&#8217;яті через засоби зв&#8217;язку веде якась невідома рятівниця, доки його переслідує якесь незбагненне лихо.</p>
<p>Однак на відміну від інших блукалок від першої особи світ SOMA — не порожня декорація з куцими уривками зі щоденника. Хоч людство припинило своє існування невдовзі до початку подій гри, героєві все ж трапляється чимало персонажів, як у кадрі, так і поза ним. З багатьма можна поспілкуватися, аби перейнятися жахом їхнього напівживого становища. Деякі діалоги варті того, аби стати цитатами для майбутніх науково-фантастичних художніх творів (хоча насправді більшість влучних фраз із SOMA цитують книжки і фільми золотої доби кіберпанку та наукової-фантастики).</p>
<p>Вразили моменти, де зустрічаєш розумних напівживих істот і для подальшого просування тобі треба їх вбивати. Вони конають, кричать, страждають, але нічого не вдієш, інакше не пройдеш. Це викликає щось близьке до жаху та огиди до самого себе.</p>
<div><img class="size-full wp-image-23306" src="http://playua.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/841442c842195e60e8a95790e4ca2fbe1.jpg" alt="Вона боролася за життя до останнього, але споживала забагато енергії, тож Саймону довелося її вбити..."   /><p class="wp-caption-text">Вона боролася за життя до останнього, але споживала забагато енергії, тож Саймону довелося її вбити&#8230;</p></div>
<p>Основна риторика гри обертається довкола питання про те, що значить бути людиною. І йдеться зовсім не про гуманізм, який протиставляється жорстокості, ні. Наразі розглядається ідентичність індивіда, як розуміної живої істоти. Протягом усієї гри персонажі запитують у гравця: де межа за якою ти більше не маєш права називатися людиною, хоч ти досі мислиш, відчуваєш і мрієш. Відповідей на це питання ніхто не дає і в цьому найсильніша особливість сюжету SOMA.</p>
<p>Проте, на жаль, про природу всього, що відбувається довкола творці гри вирішили не просто розповісти, а розжувати, перетерти, розрідити і вколоти кількаразово просто в мозок, щоби у жодному разі, не дай боже, ви нічого не проґавили. А віковий рейтинг у SOMA, нагадаю, — 17+ — ще рік і ти громадянин, що має право обирати чинну владу та зі зброєю в руках боронити кордони своєї землі. Чому розробники не залишили цим майже зрілим людям, ані шансу на таємницю, загадку, у якій можна було б розібратися самотужки, співставивши знайдені уривки інформації? Ні, усі загадки руйнуються кількаразовим повторенням одних і тих же пояснень у різній формі. І це найбільша біда сюжету SOMA.</p>
<p>Незалежно від того чи любите ви розлогу багатошарову інтригу, а чи задовольняєтеся лінійним переказом історії, вам все одно буде цікаво розслідувати, що сталося на PATHOS-2.</p>
<h3>Про недострах</h3>
<p>SOMA продається у STEAM, передусім, як гра жанру HORROR, однак від горору у SOMA лишилася тільки &#8220;Г&#8221; — настільки мало тут чогось лячного.</p>
<p>Мені, людині боязкій, що не любить скрімери, нудотники, кров по стінах і кишки на ялинці, такий вміст страху, відчаю, жаху і збентежння, які присутні у SOMA, видається оптимальним. Однак справжні адепти цегельних фабрик не знайдуть для себе тут ані моменту навіть бодай для малесенької цеглинки&#8230; Граюся сам, у навушниках, без світла, в порожній квартирі, і хоч би тьохнуло десь під серцем, а дзузьки.</p>

  <div><div><div><img   src="http://playua.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/40d87531e2507edef2fb9d0b5a3244de.jpg" class="attachment-full" alt="Кілька миттєвостей зіткнення з ворогом. Переважно передсмертних миттєвостей..." />
    <p class='slide-caption'>
    Кілька миттєвостей зіткнення з ворогом. Переважно передсмертних миттєвостей&#8230;
    </p></div><div><img   src="http://playua.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/2645f5d77653c4d86098501017321bff.jpg" class="attachment-full" alt="2015-09-30_00009" /></div><div><img   src="http://playua.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/e2ec683c20abf40c831a15948385e01e.jpg" class="attachment-full" alt="2015-09-30_00007" /></div><div><img   src="http://playua.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/18171d083df5a90937ecba62942fee34.jpg" class="attachment-full" alt="2015-09-29_00010" /></div><div><img   src="http://playua.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/68cb6a2ec376d22d4b07ea6e6c828cf3.jpg" class="attachment-full" alt="2015-09-28_00003" /></div><div><img   src="http://playua.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/193339d489688fcb0693951e7050de0b.jpg" class="attachment-full" alt="2015-09-26_00009" /></div></div></div>

<p>У Frictional Games добре знають, що атмосферу гри на 50% формує звук. Тому над ним у SOMA попрацювали дуже добре. Найбільше заслуговує на похвалу художнє рішення, щодо напівживого звучання різних механічних рухів. Наприклад викручування гермозапору із шлюзової брами віддалено нагадує крик, деформація конструкції станції під тиском води нагадує кроки і гупання десь за стіною. Таких прикладів чимало і вони переконують, що все довкола справжнє.</p>
<p>Але звукові та відеоефекти, які мали би нагнітати тривогу, насправді працюють, як попередження, що скоро буде скрімер. Усі обвали, поломки, закривання і відкривання дверей гримлять несамовито, що теж мало би лякати раптовістю, але коли я чекаю, що зараз має щось впасти, то раптовість не стається. Ба більше, при наближенні до чудовиська, яке може боляче стукнути Саймона, на безпечній відстані у полі зору гравця з&#8217;являється цифровий шум, а якщо в темряві перед вами постає ворог, то взагалі починає тремтіти ґеймпад, а тому завжди є шанс сховатися чи втекти. Додайте до цього можливість зберігатися будь-якої миті і зрозумієте, що занурення у гливку атмосферу предковічного жаху не відбувається.</p>
<p>Нагадаю, що продають у Steam зовсім не це, а жахастик від творців Amnesia і Penumbra. І фанати чекають на новий жах, а жах не приходить. Приходить тільки збентеження і звичайний острах &#8220;Ой, я впаду&#8221; або &#8220;Ой, воно мене розчавить&#8221;. Не більше. Горорна складова зводиться до раптових гучних звуків та до гри в хованки з божевільним роботом/мутантом/рибою.</p>
<div><img class="size-full wp-image-23314" src="http://playua.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/93c37ec0986958c90c0c08a57bdf2a50.jpg" alt="Остання людина на землі. А ви думали це має бути бородатий недоумок?"   /><p class="wp-caption-text">Остання людина на Землі. А ви думали це має бути бородатий недоумок?</p></div>
<p>SOMA орієнтована на масового споживача, не лише на поціновувачів горорів. Саме тому доволі часто в обговоренні гри можна натрапити на порівняння з Cradle. Нічого дивного, адже поціновувачі тиць-клац пригод знайдуть у новому творінні Frictional Games для себе значно більше цікавого і нового, аніж прихильники старих добрих жахів. Та ще й нерви полоскочуть незвичними для них втечами з пересиджуванням у темних куточках, доки щось лиховісне скрадається поруч коридором. Словом, навіть у The Vanishing of Ethan Carter було більше жаху, аніж у SOMA.</p>
<p>А якщо глянути на приховане донедавна видиво з зображенням альтернативного початку гри, стає зрозуміло, що розробники свідомо знизили психологічне навантаження на гравця, зробивши гру значно менш страшною, аніж задумувалося спочатку. Саме тому стало значно легше насолоджуватися сюжетом, неквапно роздивлятися заготовлені підводні краєвиди та розмірковувати над сенсом буття.</p>
<p>Альтернативний початок SOMA:</p>
<div>
<div><iframe></iframe></div>
<p></div>
<p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlXtvymTdV0&#038;feature=youtu.be" data-rel="lightbox-video-0" class="arve-hidden">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlXtvymTdV0&amp;feature=youtu.be</a></p>
<p>А ще таким чином гра значно ліпше продається. Адже тепер її аудиторія складається не лише з дванадцятилітніх писклявих нумограйників, а й з отих заповітних 17+, яким не потрібні батьки, щоби придбати забавку. Отже покупців у SOMA буде значно більше, ніж у попередніх ігор Frictional Games. Віва, ля комерція!</p>
<h3>Про атмосферу</h3>
<p>Тим не менше атмосфера гри цілісна, багатогранна. У ній хочеться порпатися, її хочеться пропускати крізь себе, зазирнувши у кожну щілину та відкривши кожну скриньку, шафку, кабінку з трупом тощо.</p>
<p>І не дивно, адже сюжет на висоті (хоча зліплений із давно використаних шаблонів з «Матриці», «Чорного дзеркала», «Горизонту подій», Dead Space, System Shock, Bioshock тощо). Світ живий (хоча він вмер). Лякалки&#8230; ну, вони могли б спрацювати (хоч вони більше схожі на повідомлення: отут страшно, бійся), але справжнього страху не викликають. Завдання і головоломки різноманітні, хоча подання і просування за сюжетом циклічно повторюється (тут є своєрідні рівні і вони зациклені). Це хороша гра для широкої публіки, але вміст не відповідає опису в крамниці.</p>
<p><img class="size-full wp-image-23315" src="http://playua.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/99b3ec574294d5be0183c5ec45cb1bbc.jpg" alt="Друзяка... Миле, добре створіннячко. Шкода, що і його довелося вбити..."   /></p>
<p>Друзяка&#8230; Миле, добре створіннячко. Шкода, що і його довелося вбити&#8230;</p>
<p>До речі про циклічність рівнів. Структура просування за сюжетом зводиться до стандартних етапів:</p>
<ol>
<li>Дослідження станції.</li>
<li>Пошук виходу.</li>
<li>Пересування під водою.</li>
<li>Пошук входу на наступну станцію.</li>
<li>Усе спочатку.</li>
</ol>
<p>Звісно, станції різні, як за архітектурою, так і за пригодами на них, але якби викинути з гри 3-4 однакові цикли (рівні), то сюжетно і атмосферно вона б нічого не втратила, але стала би на 5 годин коротшою. А масовий споживач не любить 18 баксів за 5 годин лінійної тиць-клац пригоди з псевдо страшними ворогами. Тому маємо штучне, хоч і майстерно виконане, затягування хронометражу забавки.</p>
<h3>Про ігролад</h3>
<p>Мабуть, ви звернули у вагу, що в цьому огляді ГРИ дуже мало сказано саме грання та ігролад. Це тому, що його тут збіса мало. Майже стільки ж, скільки у Dear Esther. Ну, гаразд, трохи більше. Тут можна не лише рухатися вперед, а також натискати кнопки, розгадувати прості головоломки тощо.</p>
<p>О, а ще є стелс-механіка! Ну, як стелс&#8230; Просто можна не тільки ходити і бігати, а й скрадатися, коли поруч бродить глухе і тупе чудовисько. Іноді, коли чудовисько за вами погналося, можна просто сісти в куточку та повернутися до нього дупою. Ображене таким ставленням, чудовисько розвернеться і піде собі далі. Оце й усі ігроладні особливості SOMA.</p>
<p><img class="size-full wp-image-23316" src="http://playua.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/6ab76b78e9615cb9ba984fcd478f48a2.jpg" alt="Вона не вміла скрадатися і була надто гучною, але тепер лежить тихенько..."   /></p>
<p>Вона не вміла скрадатися і була надто гучною, але тепер лежить тихенько&#8230;</p>
<p>Слід відзначити, що вона несамовито прекрасно грається за допомогою ґеймпада. Навіть тоді, коли Саймону дають постріляти по роботу з енергетичної зброї. І як я відзначав раніше, вібрація ґеймпаду додає вражень під час проходження. Тож раджу не псувати собі вражень на клавомиші.</p>
<h3>Про графіку</h3>
<p>На перший погляд у SOMA графоній не завезли. Чомусь у вступному рівні картинка некрасива ні технічно, ні навіть художньо. Але з просуванням уперед графіка дивовижним чином розквітає. Додаються деталі об&#8217;єктам, накладаються все нові і нові ефекти. Особливо гарно стає після того, як Саймон отримує першого потиличника від когось із ворогів і після того довго на екрані усе стає на доволі тривалий час барвистіше, трішки двоїться, нагадує старі фотографії. Якось дивно.</p>
<div><img class="size-full wp-image-23317" src="http://playua.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/ad92db686518b080db2310c4b85d17c6.jpg" alt="Зовсім не таке очікуєш, коли виставляєш налаштування графіки на повну."   /><p class="wp-caption-text">Зовсім не таке очікуєш, коли виставляєш налаштування графіки на повну.</p></div>
<p>Пізніше вражень додають мандри по морському дні. І чим ближче до фіналу, тим красивішими стають ці мандри. З&#8217;являються нові істоти, вода збурюється, усе ворушиться, довкола летять уламки станції, шматки мертвих водоростів і хмари мулу, булькотить термальне джерело і світяться таємничі поріддя структурного гелю.</p>
<h3>Про жертву сподівань</h3>
<p>У день релізу провідні і не дуже видання наввипередки осипали SOMA захмарно високими оцінками. І незрозуміло чому. Схоже, тут спрацював якийсь стадний інстинкт і всі повиставляли грі оцінки з огляду на чийсь авторитет. На щастя з плином часу, як це зазвичай і буває, ейфорія від знайомства з новою непоганою грою пішла на спад і оцінка гри впала до 77 балів зі 100 і це ближче до істини.</p>
<p>Гра справді непогана і її творців можна було би похвалити, якби ними були якісь Вася і Петя з Жашкова, що за батьківські гроші купували мівінку, доки робили цю гру у позанавчальний час. Але ж, бляха, SOMA зробили творці Amnesia, від якої гравці вкривалися липким потом на кожному кроці, а поява переслідувача ледь не вирубала їх від жаху, особливо, коли він добігав до дверей, за якими ті марно намагався заховатися.</p>
<div><img class="size-full wp-image-23318" src="http://playua.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/ae757a75c4dc03898f3cfc97e231dd5e.jpg" alt="Доволі незвичний спосіб поліпшення самопочуття. Я би сказав, через сраку."   /><p class="wp-caption-text">Доволі незвичний спосіб поліпшення самопочуття. Я би сказав, через сраку.</p></div>
<p>Звісно, є невеличке розчарування через завищені сподівання. Але якщо змінити своє ставлення і розглядати SOMA, як цілісний самодостатній художній твір з елементами відстороненого жаху, то перед нами постає цікава, красива, захоплива драма про мандри самотніх душ у цифровому потойбіччі.</p>
<p>А якщо бездумно вірити опису в крамниці, то маємо лагідний, передбачуваний жахастик з порожніми, коридорними локаціями і повторюваними рівнями.</p>
<p>Словом, <a href="/game/soma/">SOMA</a> — чудова гра. І комфортна, і цікава. Просто не горор.</p>
```

So this html contains some tags, cleaned by my algorithm. Most common tags are `<p>`, `<div>` and `<img>` and almost all images are FullHD.

The problem happens then setting such html string to `HtmlView.Html` property, app memory usage goes up to 190MB. Such behaviour causes app crash on low-memory Windows Phone devices and rarely on devices with 1GB of RAM. If app not crashes, memory usage decreases to 30-40MB. So in general to show such html string, even with some FullHD images, 30-40MB is enough. You can see example from Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0IQH.png]

Is there any way to reduce memory usage for MyToolkit HtmlView control when setting Html property?